# Sending data from Kinesis Analytics to Kinesis Firehose not working

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have added Kinesis Firehose Stream as a destination to the Kinesis Analytics Service. Data is properly getting inserted into Kinesis Analytics, but is unable to reach the Kinesis Firehose stream.

Have granted all the Kinesis permissions to the IAM role associated with Kinesis Destination, and also with Firehose stream.

Unable to find the error.

Can anyone please help with what is going wrong? Can't see any error anywhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to define and insert data into the DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM in the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

The common scenario i have seen is the following.

1. Defining an IN application Stream.
2. Mentioning the IN application stream specifially in the destination stream.

[image]